# How do I stop Swift from injecting escaped single quotes in my [String]?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, escaping, single-quotes

I'm attempting to print out a string array without escaped single quotes. For some reason, Swift is injecting escaped single quotes when printing my array. This has a trickle down problem when I use the array to build JSON. JSON ends up not being able to parse due to the escaped single quotes.

I thought this was a problem with my code, but I've distilled this down to a single usecase that should be straightforward.

```swift
let names = ["Tommy 'Tiny' Lister", "Tom Hanks"]
print(names)
```

The output is:

["Tommy \'Tiny\' Lister", "Tom Hanks"]

> Note: I did not include escaped single quotes in my names array.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Here is the what I'm doing later in code to create JSON. For purposes of brevity, this is a really dumbed down version of what I'm doing:

```
var names = ["Tommy Tiny Lister", "Tom Hanks"]

var jsonString = """
{"names": \(names)}
"""

var jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)

if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!) as? [String: Any] {
    let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted)
    let string = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
    print(string!)
}
```

Comment: That is just the debug representation of the string

Comment: Yes but when I add this array to generate JSON, the escaped quotes come along... Might take a minute for me to post an example...

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is using Swift arrays' `description` to generate JSON:

```
var jsonString = """
{"names": \(names)}
""" // your JSON will contain name.description
```

You are relying on the fact that the implementation of `description` just so happens to result in the same format as JSON *most of the time*. As you can see, when there are `'` in the array elements, the description is not valid JSON.

Basically, you should not rely on the `description` to generate JSON. Instead, you should use `Codable` to generate JSON data from a Swift array.

For the JSON you want to produce:

```
{
    "names": ["Tommy 'Tiny' Lister", "Tom Hanks"]
}
```

You can use a struct like this:

```
struct Names : Codable {
    let names: [String]
}
```

And then you can produce JSON `Data` like this:

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
do {
    let obj = Names(names: ["Tommy 'Tiny' Lister", "Tom Hanks"])
    let data = try encoder.encode(obj)
} catch { ... }
```

Comment: Yeah... Duh... I guess I was making a bad assumption... I should probably do this everywhere. Thanks for this!

Comment: @TNo if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!